# Get points of a square ROI from a resolution

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I need the points for create a centered squared ROI How to calculate it? Im using opencv-python.

**Example:
Resolution: 800x448

Points of ROI: (210,34),(590,414)**

Centered ROI must be an square like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj80K.png

I need the points for 1920x1080 and 1280x720

Comment: Thanks but I dont know the values of row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a center crop (of 1080x1080) as follows in Python/OpenCV.

```
# get the center of your current ROI 
# (half way between top-left and bottom-right points)
cx = x1 + (x2 - 1 - x1)/2
cy = y1 + (y2 - 1 - y1)/2

# get the smaller of the two current ROI dimensions
w = h = min((x2-1-x1),(y2-1-y1))

# get top left part of ROI of square region
xt = int(cx - w/2)
yt = int(cy - h/2)

# get bottom right part of ROI of square
xb = xt + w
yb = yt + h

square ROI = image[yt:yb, xt:xb]
```

Comment: Thanks but  I'm still confused about how to get a 1230x1230 square centered ROI in a 1920x1080 image.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and gave you the formula for the minimum enclosing square, so a 1080x1080 center crop. To do the other, you would need to insert your full image into the center of a 1230x1230 background image, say black. Or you could then convert the black to transparent by supply a mask as the alpha channel. If you need help, I can provide more details tomorrow.

Comment: You say "I need a 1230 square ROI centered in a 1920x1080 image." But that makes no sense. How do you put a 1230x1230 image into a smaller 1920x1080?  What do you really want?  Do you mean you want the center 1920x1080 ROI from the 1230x1230 image cropped out? Please clarify!

Comment: Sorry if my words were confusing, a little mistake of me. I mean, something like that: https://ibb.co/98c97Vq

Comment: That is what I gave  you already where the square size is the largest it could be for the given width and height. You can just change `w = h = any size smaller than the min(w,h)`

Comment: I see. But what is x1,x2,y1,y2 ?

Comment: The bounds of the original 1920x1080 ROI as you wrote `ROI = image[y1:y2, x1:x2].`  I read your post meaning that you cut a 1920x1080 ROI from a larger image and wanted the square region from its center. If that is not what you wanted, please be much more clear about your requirements and specifications.

Comment: If you need further help, please rewrite your question more clearly within the requirements of this forum (see the help section) and have it reopened. I can then try again to answer your clarified question.

Comment: x1,x2,y1,y2 are the top left and bottom right corners of your input 1920x1080 ROI or input image, if you are starting with a full image.

Comment: I've rewrited the question.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your rewritten question. Are you starting with a 1920x1080 full image or is that an ROI of a larger image?  What size do you want for the final square ROI? If you are starting with a full image, then set x1=y1=0 and x2=1920, y2=1080 in my code above.  Decide on the dimension of the center ROI, say it is 800x800 square (must be smaller than 1080). Then put w=h=800 in my code above and the result `ROI = image[yt:yb, xt:xb]` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :D I did it https://ibb.co/GvW3rwT